# Close Print Popout with PHPunit Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, browser-automation

I'm learning `PHPUNIT` at the moment. It was getting interesting until i got stuck on something.

I "logged-in" it and went well,

But this `PrintOut` just displays. Is there anyway I could remove it?

Actually I just want to get the value of the Surname, FirstName and the the picture most importantly, the picture.

The picture is saved as `/ImagePage.aspx`. Is there a way in which I can download this and force close the browser because I don't know how to close the `print Pop-out`

The picture frame id is `CandImg`

This is my code:

```
<?php
class TestLogin extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase 
{

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://localhost/tutor');
    }


   public function setSpeed($timeInMilliSec)
   {
       $this->setSpeed('120');
   }

    /*Function to locate website*/
    public function testHasLoginForm()
    {
        $this->url('http://www.jamb.org.ng/DirectEntry/');/*This is the site*/
        $username = $this->byId('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RegNumber');/*Search for a name*/
        $this->assertContains('Reg.Number/PIN', $username->value());
        ##ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtRegNumber
        $action = $this->byName('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Reprint')->attribute('action');
        $this->byId('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RegNumber')->value('49003257DE');/*value of the textbox*/
        $jump = $this->byName('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Reprint');
        $this->byName('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Reprint')->click();
    }           

}    
#to Save ImagePage.aspx
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for editing the question.... i really appreciate, but if there's an answer..I will be just super fine with it

Comment: to close the browser: $this->webDriver->close();